# Internet not working properly in DELL XPS 13 9370

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, xps

I have removed windows from my machine and work only on Ubuntu 18. I can connect to the wifi easily without any problems. The net connection stays solid for 30-40 minutes and suddenly stops working. Then I switch off the wifi option in the laptop, then switch it on again and it starts working again. I have searched a lot of forums but they only have issues relating to drivers/ or the wifi not connected.

### As requested by Jeremy31

https://termbin.com/wps5

Comment: It seems like this is a common complaint with XPS 13's wireless card.  and Many are replacing the one that come with the machine with and intel that works better. here is a page that may be of help though: [link] https://joshschertz.com/2017/08/06/Wireless-Issues-with-Ubuntu-on-the-Dell-XPS-13/

Comment: Please run the 2 commands at https://gist.github.com/jeremyb31/a2bee9856d8c13f42f1835bc31bf9480 in terminal and post the termbin URL after the second command is run

Comment: https://termbin.com/wps5

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue on my new Dell XPS, but after looking at the post install scripts for [dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin](https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin) and testing to replace the drivers for the wifi-card the problem disappeared.

The exact commands I used:

```
# Install wifi drivers
mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/* ~/BackupDrivers/.
wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin?raw=true
wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin?raw=true
wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1?raw=true
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I noticed was the power saved is enabled. That sometimes can give trouble with drop outs on wifi.  You can turn that off as follows

When WiFi Power Management is on, proceed as follows.

In order to prevent typo's, copy/paste this line into the terminal (it's one line!):

sudo -i gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

Press Enter.

Now a text file opens. In that text file, you see the following content:

[connection] wifi.powersave = 3

Change 3 into 2.

Save the modified file and close it.

c. Reboot your computer.